# RSA Algorithm - don't want to find 'd'

Tags: rsa

Is there any 'p' ,'q' and 'e' that can't find any 'd' for it?

for example with this parameters:

q=13 , p=7 , e=25
we can find d=49 for it with this:

```
(e * d) % (12 * 6) = 1
```

but i want 'p', 'q' and 'e' that no 'd' can find for it...

is it possible or not?

Comment: If `gcd(e, phi(pq)) != 1` then yes, however such a choice is banned .. for this reason.

Comment: What would be the point? You could never decrypt, which would make RSA useless.

Comment: yes I know I can't decrypt anymore but it's a research project.
can you help me, please?